# Что значит "временная структура таблицы для представления"?

Tags: mysql

Кусок sql-кода из дампа базы данных:

```
--
-- Temporary table structure for view `payments`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `payments`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `payments`*/;
/*!50001 CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `id` int(9) unsigned zerofill,
  ...
  `allow` tinyint(1),
  `receipt` blob
) */;
```

Что это вообще значит, "временная структура таблицы для представления"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**mysqldump** сохраняет представления в два этапа:

1. сначала создаются временные таблицы с такими же структурами, как и у
   представлений.
2. после этого временные таблицы уничтожаются и
   создаются непосредственно сами представления.

Такой подход необходим, потому что представления могут зависеть друг от друга. В таком случае их нужно  воссоздавать в определенном порядке. mysqldump не может определить такие зависимости, поэтому сначала создает временные таблицы для отображения всей структуры, а это в свою очередь обеспечивает корректное создание представлений вне зависимости от порядка.

Comment: а при создании дампа в SQLyog также используется mysqldump?

Comment: и ещё один вопрос: если удалить эту временную структуру таблицы для представления, но оставить создание собственно представления, то представление не создастся?

Comment: Насчет SQLyog не знаю, обычно я делаю дампы с помощью консоли. Ваш кусок кода из дампа точно такой, как и при mysqldump, поэтому я и подумал, что вопрос о нем. Если удалить создание временной таблицы, то представление должно все равно создаться (только что проверил)